# Debugger for Chrome in VSCode - variables not available

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, visual-studio-code

I've launched Chrome debugging of my React application:

```
{
  "type": "chrome",
  "request": "launch",
  "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
  "url": "http://localhost:8080",
  "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
}
```

When application runs, it stops at breakpoints e.g. :

```
  isActive(index) {
    return index === this.state.activePanelIndex;
  }
```

However in `Debug Console` nor `Watch` windows I have access to variables e.g. (not hovering over):

> index ReferenceError: index is not defined
>
> this.state.activePanelIndex TypeError: Cannot read property
>
> 'activePanelIndex' of undefined this.state undefined

Why is that? How can I fixed?